How do I optimise queries for combined criteria in a large SQL Database?
I have a ~280GB SQLite DB with company financial info which I am running various queries against. Yes it's SQLite because it works fine and is simpler to work with.  I have a MySQL version of this DB too but I'd rather avoid using it if I can.
There is a table called ItemValues with a billion or so rows. Every single column shown in the two tables below has an index which is built at the time of DB build job (overnight)



CompanyId
ItemTypeId
NumericValue
DateEpoch




AB1234
1
100
1569884400


AB1234
2
200
1569884400


G17895
7
50
1632956400



The ItemTypeId is a foreign key and the table it refers to , called ItemTypes looks like this



Id
ItemShortDescription




1
Cost


2
Revenue


3
SomeOtherFinancialMetric1


4
SomeOtherFinancialMetric2



I can lookup companies with a specific Cost OR Revenue quite easily and the search takes milliseconds to return results.
Here is the SQL Fiddle
The problem arises when I have to lookup companies which meet a specific Cost AND Revenue criteria. While technically I can lookup all companies with a specific Cost, then lookup all companies with a specific Revenue and then combine the two, selecting only the subset of companies that meet both my criteria, this approach returns a ton of data as there millions upon millions of rows that match Cost (Revenue isn't found in as many rows of ItemValues, in relative terms).
What options might I have to solve this challenge? At present I am only searching on Cost and Revenue and I suppose I could add these two values to each ItemValues but the fields I need to search on may grow. I'm wondering if my table design needs rethinking, or perhaps I should look into column oriented DBs but I believe I should first try to optimise querying against the existing db structure.
SQL Fiddle contents:
CREATE TABLE ItemTypes (
    Id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    ItemShortDescription TEXT
);

CREATE INDEX idx_ItemTypes_ItemShortDescription ON ItemTypes (ItemShortDescription);

INSERT INTO ItemTypes (Id, ItemShortDescription) VALUES (1, 'Cost');
INSERT INTO ItemTypes (Id, ItemShortDescription) VALUES (2, 'Revenue');
INSERT INTO ItemTypes (Id, ItemShortDescription) VALUES (3, 'SomeOtherFinancialMetric1');
INSERT INTO ItemTypes (Id, ItemShortDescription) VALUES (4, 'SomeOtherFinancialMetric2');

CREATE TABLE ItemValues (
    CompanyId TEXT,
    ItemTypeId INTEGER,
    NumericValue INTEGER,
    DateEpoch INTEGER
);

CREATE INDEX idx_ItemValues_CompanyId ON ItemValues (CompanyId);
CREATE INDEX idx_ItemValues_ItemTypeId ON ItemValues (ItemTypeId);
CREATE INDEX idx_ItemValues_NumericValue ON ItemValues (NumericValue);
CREATE INDEX idx_ItemValues_DateEpoch ON ItemValues (DateEpoch);

INSERT INTO ItemValues (CompanyId, ItemTypeId, NumericValue, DateEpoch) VALUES ('AB1234', 1, 100, 1569884400);
INSERT INTO ItemValues (CompanyId, ItemTypeId, NumericValue, DateEpoch) VALUES ('AB1234', 2, 200, 1569884400);
INSERT INTO ItemValues (CompanyId, ItemTypeId, NumericValue, DateEpoch) VALUES ('G17895', 7, 50, 1632956400);

WITH salesIdsCTE AS (
    SELECT Id 
    FROM ItemTypes 
    WHERE ItemShortDescription = 'Cost' Or ItemShortDescription = 'Revenue'
),
filteredReportItems AS (
    SELECT * 
    FROM ItemValues 
    WHERE ItemTypeId IN (SELECT Id FROM salesIdsCTE)
    AND NumericValue > 5
)
SELECT *
FROM filteredReportItems
LIMIT 5;


The query in the fiddle only filters on Cost. Can you post the full query? (Also please add the contents of the fiddle to the question so if the site goes down in the future, the question is still useful for others.)

Also the fiddle doesn't mention what indexes you have.

Thank you. All the columns are indexed and I have added the fiddle contents (including the indexes this time). Not fully sure what else would be helpful to add in terms of full query. The query posted isn't different from how I'm running the queries on the actual DB

I think the query you've written will not do Cost > 5 AND Revenue > 5, it will do an OR.

Can't you just join the table to itself - in one instance pick up the revenue records for a company and in the other instance pick up the cost records for the same company?

An index on ItemValues(ItemTypeId, NumericValue) might be useful. See https://sqlite.org/queryplanner.html and https://sqlite.org/cli.html#index_recommendations_sqlite_expert_ and https://sqlite.org/eqp.html

Single-column indexes are very often not helpful, and you should only create them when really needed. Will you ever write a query to ask "give me all rows where one of the measures (I don't care which type) is between 20 and 30"? I doubt that. So, what is the index on NumericValue alone good for?

Thanks all, single column index being potentially useless here hadn't occurred to me

Of course it is much faster to find particular rows in a table (e.g. all rows matching ItemTypeId = 1 and NumericValue > 5), than selecting two such (possibly huge) data sets and then join them.
You say you want rows matching Cost AND Revenue criteria, but the query you have is looking for rows matching Cost OR Revenue criteria.
One correct query would be:
SELECT companyid FROM itemvalues WHERE itemtypeid = 1 AND numericvalue > 5
INTERSECT
SELECT companyid FROM itemvalues WHERE itemtypeid = 2 AND numericvalue > 5;

The most appropriate index for this would be
CREATE INDEX idx ON itemvalues(numericvalue, itemtypeid, companyid);

This index is especially helpful, if the requested values are very high and apply only to a small amount of the table rows. Thus the DBMS could rule out most of the rows right away and only run through a small part of the index. That table itself wouldn't have to be read, as all the information is available in the index. (This is called a covering index).
Another way to write the query is:
SELECT companyid
FROM itemvalues
WHERE itemtypeid IN (1,2)
GROUP BY companyid
HAVING MIN(numericvalue) > 5;

where you might have to adjust the HAVING clause. IF it is possible for a company to lack type 1 or 2, you'd have to add AND COUNT(*) = 2 or the like to ensure that both values exist and are above 5. If you are looking for different values, you might need conditional aggregation, e.g. HAVING MIN(numericvalue) FILTER (WHERE itemtypeid = 1) > 5 AND MIN(numericvalue) FILTER (WHERE itemtypeid = 2) > 10.
For this query the index should start with the ItemTypeId, as this is what we first filter the rows by. As there exist but few types, though, we can assume that a big part of the rows are affected by itemtypeid IN (1,2). (Maybe even half the table.) For this reason this index only makes sense when it is a covering index, so the table must not be read, as already mentioned:
CREATE INDEX idx ON itemvalues(itemtypeid, numericvalue, companyid);

At last: yes, another table design would be more appropriate for this kind of query. With separate columns for the different types you would again just be looking for single rows matching criteria:
CREATE TABLE company (
    companyid         INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    companyname       TEXT,
    cost              INTEGER,
    cost_dateepoch    INTEGER
    revenue           INTEGER,
    revenue_dateepoch INTEGER
);

SELECT * FROM company WHERE cost > 5 AND revenue > 5;

No index needed, as reading the whole table sequentially is the fastest approach anyway. But you'd lack the flexibility to add new metrics whenever you like or even have them added by users for their own purposes.

Thank you, what a great, detailed answer( chatgpt failed me here) you have given me two or three things I can try. I'll try adding a covering index and try the query with the having clause and add my results here soon

Update: I added the covering index CREATE INDEX idx ON itemvalues(numericvalue, itemtypeid, companyid);   and it now the results are returned in a few milliseconds. Thank you!!
